# Is it secure to expose OAuth2 credentials for a test application

Tags: oauth2

I have created an application in which it is possible to login using GitLab. This requires an OAuth2 app id and secret.

I created a test application in GitLab UI with the redirect set to https://localhost:9999 for local development.

Since the redirect URL is on localhost, I wonder if there are any security concerns when committing this app id and secret. It is definitely convenient.